# Wireless Network not working for Broadcom Corporation BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4353] (rev 01)

Tags: 14.04, drivers, broadcom

I've searched a lot for my driver but didn't get any solution. I referred to this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers?noredirect=1&lq=1) where it gives solution under "Special Case #1 " but that doesn't give me a clear solution.
here is few info if it is required:

`lspci -vnn | grep Network` gives

`00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10ea] (rev 05)
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4353] (rev 01)`

`iwconfig` gives

`eno1      no wireless extensions.`

`lo        no wireless extensions.`

`enp0s29u1u2  no wireless extensions.`

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
also this:
[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NR6OV.png)

Comment: *Special Case #1 - Uses bcma and brcmsmac driver combination. Required firmware is installed by default in the package linux-firmware.* What is not clear? What is your output of `lspci -knn | grep net -A 3` ?  Whats the output of `ifconfig -a`?

Comment: like how to install bcma and brcmsmac..
output of your given command is [here](https://imgur.com/xoQ4LsL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image link suggests that the wrong driver is installed. Please remove it. From the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Reboot.

Check to see that the correct driver, *brcmsmac* loaded:

```
lsmod | grep brcmsmac
```

Check for informative clues in the log:

```
dmesg | grep brcm
```